# coredata nspredicate NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

What 's wrong with predicate format below ?

```
    if (devices && devices.count > 0 && ![tf_Search.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
    NSString* strSearch = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", tf_Search.text];
    NSPredicate* preFilter =
        [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(dRIV_NAMESURNAME CONTAINS[cd] %1$@) || (vEHI_PLATE CONTAINS[cd] %1$@)",
                     strSearch];
    devicesFitered = [devices filteredArrayUsingPredicate:preFilter];
}
```

devicesFiltered array s not null and has 4 coredata device entity.

dRIV_NAMESURNAME and vEHI_PLATE are entity fields. NSString.

it gives > "'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string" error

if i use them seperatelly like in below 2 formats, no problem

@"(dRIV_NAMESURNAME CONTAINS[cd] %@)" > no problem

or

@"(vEHI_PLATE CONTAINS[cd] %@)" > no problem

is it about %1$@ ?

is it not possible in objc to address inputs like in cSharp "{1} asdas da {1} sdfs {2}"

What is the correct format ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No %1$@ is not permitted.  The easiest solution is just to repeat the `strSearch` argument:

```
    NSPredicate* preFilter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(dRIV_NAMESURNAME CONTAINS[cd] %@) || (vEHI_PLATE CONTAINS[cd] %@)", strSearch, strSearch];
```

If you have a very long predicate with many duplicated arguments, you could also consider using `NSPredicate`'s `predicateWithSubstitutionVariables` method.  See the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSPredicate/predicateWithSubstitutionVariables:).